# How to override the UI change of a UITextField when it gets Focus on tvOS?

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield, focus, tvos

My issue is pretty simple. I have a UITextField in a view displayed on tvOS. When the UITextField gets the Focus, the textfield looks like zoomed in. The effect is not bad, even if undesired, but I added a border colored and the border is not scaled within the textfield.

Here is a code example to reproduce :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UITextField* textFieldExample1 = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 700, 100)];
    [[self view] addSubview:textFieldExample1];
    [[textFieldExample1 layer] setBorderWidth:2];
    [[textFieldExample1 layer] setBorderColor:[[UIColor cyanColor] CGColor]];

    UITextField* textFieldExample2 = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 110, 700, 100)];
    [[self view] addSubview:textFieldExample2];
    [[textFieldExample2 layer] setBorderWidth:2];
    [[textFieldExample2 layer] setBorderColor:[[UIColor cyanColor] CGColor]];
}
```

[image: Textfield with focus]

[image: Textfield without focus]

Comment: @JakobMikkelsen Sorry but calling setNeedsDisplay and setNeedsLayout doesn't change anything on the animation of the textfield.

Comment: Did you get any solution for the same?

Comment: @DeepKSOreadytohelp I did not get any solution. My fallback was to use only the default basic focus for Textfields. One other workarround that worked partially was to put the textfield inside a view of the same size with clips to bounds set to YES : the zoom effect is still present but less annoying. You can then put the border effect on the super view... but it still pretty lame.

Comment: Thanks bro for your time, I will try this one and if I get better solution/result I will let you know :)

Answer (score -1):

Try to subclass UITextField, and then implement didUpdateFocusInContext there.

Something like this:

```
override func didUpdateFocusInContext(context: UIFocusUpdateContext, withAnimationCoordinator coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) {

    coordinator.addCoordinatedAnimations({ () -> Void in

        // remove or give custom look to your shadow here

        }, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the trick but it doesn't really suits me and introduce a new issue. The solution you provide only prevent the animation of the super class to be called and may have unexpected effects since we don't actually know what is done in the super implementation. Moreover, when I start editing the Textfield, the same weird shadow appears and never disappear since we don't call the super implementation of focus update method.